# Will Crossfire/SLI benefit Compute Shader performace?

Tags: gpgpu, directx-11, compute-shader, sli

I'm digging into DX11 Compute Shaders. And I wonder if there will be any performance increase with adding one more video card with Crossfire/SLI. Or adding one more video card without using Crossfire/SLI.

Has anyone experimented with this?

Answer (score 1):

I run a system with two Nvidia Maxwell archietcture  GPU's. I don't use Crossfire/SLI.

Crossfire/SLI  won't affect the Shader compute performance per-se.   Crossfire/SLI  manipulates the image frame rendering output  do one of several things:

1) Render a partial frame on different GPU's
2) Render alternative frames  on different GPU's
3) A combination of 1) and 2)
4) Improvements in anti-aliasing

See  http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/SLI-vs-CrossFire/391

Crossfire/SLI is useful for improving rendering performance  of images, games etc. It does nothing to
improve the compute performance.

Adding an extra  video cards without Crossfire/SLI, will benefit compute performance, if you can partition the work across the multiple GPU's without incurring too much overhead.   This can be done with CUDA and OpenCL  by creating multiple device  queues and queuing work to each device. I don't know if DX11 Shaders can do this?